# Слайдер не работает корректно

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

Изначально я был привязан к intro1/intro2/intro3(т.е поменяв 2 строчки я стал получать ошибку.
было так:
this.main = document.querySelector(selector);
this.slider = this.main.querySelector('.slider');) и соответственно в качестве селектора я передавал intro1/intro2 и тд и все работало как надо, решил привязаться сразу к слайдеру, но стал получать ошибку.
Слайдер не работает корректно, получаю ошибку "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')" у кнопок

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    
  class MySlider {

    position = 0;
    itemMargin = 0;
    
    constructor(selector, options = {}) {
      this.slidesToShow = options.slidesToShow || 1;
      this.sliderToScroll = options.sliderToScroll || 1;
      this.main = document.querySelector(selector);
      this.sliderWrapper = this.main.querySelector('.slider-wrapper');
      this.btnPrev = this.main.querySelector('.btn-prev');
      this.btnNext = this.main.querySelector('.btn-next');
      this.items = this.main.querySelectorAll('.slider-slide');
      this.itemWidth = this.main.clientWidth / this.slidesToShow;
      this.itemsLength = this.items.length;
      this.movePosition = this.sliderToScroll * this.itemWidth;
  
      this.items.forEach((item) => {
        item.style.minWidth = `${this.itemWidth}px`
      })
  
      this.btnNext.addEventListener('click', this.onNextClick.bind(this));
      this.btnPrev.addEventListener('click', this.onPrevClick.bind(this));
      this.checkBtns();
    }


    checkBtns = function() {
      this.btnPrev.disabled = this.position === 0;
      this.btnNext.disabled = this.position <= -(this.itemsLength - this.slidesToShow) * this.itemWidth;
    }
  
    setPosition = function() {
      this.sliderWrapper.style.transform = `translateX(${this.position}px)`;
    }
  
    onPrevClick = function() {
      const itemsLeft = Math.abs(this.position) / this.itemWidth;
      if (itemsLeft >= this.sliderToScroll) {
        this.position += this.movePosition;
      } else {
        this.position += this.itemsLeft * this.itemWidth;
      }
      this.setPosition();
      this.checkBtns();
    }
  
    onNextClick = function() {
      const itemsLeft = this.itemsLength - (Math.abs(this.position) + this.slidesToShow * this.itemWidth) / this.itemWidth;
      if (itemsLeft >= this.sliderToScroll) {
        this.position -= this.movePosition;
      } else {
        this.position -= this.itemsLeft * this.itemWidth;
      }
  
      this.setPosition();
      this.checkBtns();
    }
    
  }
    
  //Init Sliders

  new MySlider('.slider1', {
      slidesToShow: 3,
      sliderToScroll: 3
  });

  new MySlider('.slider2',{
      slidesToShow: 2,
      sliderToScroll: 2
  });
  
  new MySlider('.slider3');


});
```

```css
.intro {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 30px auto;
}

.slider {
    background-color: pink;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slider-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    background-color: pink;
    transition: transform .2s linear;
}

.slider-slide {
    display: flex;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.slider-slide:nth-child(3n + 1) {
      background-color: red;
  }

.slider-slide:nth-child(3n + 2) {
      background-color: green;
  }

.slider-slide:nth-child(3n + 3) {
      background-color: orange;
  }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <main class="main">
    <div class="intro">
        <div class="slider slider1">
            <div class="slider-wrapper">
                <div class="slider-slide">1</div>
                <div class="slider-slide">2</div>
                <div class="slider-slide">3</div>
                <div class="slider-slide">4</div>
                <div class="slider-slide">5</div>
                <div class="slider-slide">6</div>
                <div class="slider-slide">7</div>
                <div class="slider-slide">8</div>
                <div class="slider-slide">9</div>
            </div>
            <div class="btns">
                <button class="btn-prev">Назад</button>
                <button class="btn-next">Вперед</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="intro1">
        <div class="slider slider2">
          <div class="slider-wrapper">
            <div class="slider-slide">1</div>
            <div class="slider-slide">2</div>
            <div class="slider-slide">3</div>
            <div class="slider-slide">4</div>
            <div class="slider-slide">5</div>
            <div class="slider-slide">6</div>
            <div class="slider-slide">7</div>
            <div class="slider-slide">8</div>
            <div class="slider-slide">9</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btns">
          <button class="btn-prev">Назад</button>
          <button class="btn-next">Вперед</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="intro2">
        <div class="slider slider3">
          <div class="slider-wrapper">
            <div class="slider-slide">1</div>
            <div class="slider-slide">2</div>
            <div class="slider-slide">3</div>
            <div class="slider-slide">4</div>
            <div class="slider-slide">5</div>
            <div class="slider-slide">6</div>
            <div class="slider-slide">7</div>
            <div class="slider-slide">8</div>
            <div class="slider-slide">9</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btns">
          <button class="btn-prev">Назад</button>
          <button class="btn-next">Вперед</button>
        </div>
      </div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя кнопки он не находит, проверь, что получаешь в переменные кнопок

Comment: я почему-то получаю значения кнопок только для первого слайдера

Comment: такая глупость, я не увидел ошибку в разметке, btns были не в блоке слайдера